# c- read in line from file

Tags: c, file, input

I am new to c, but I would like to read in text from a file. I don't know the length of the first line of the file, so how can I write the correct parameters for the fgets function?
Right now I have:

```
char read[30]; // but I really don't know how long the line will be

while(fgets(read, sizeof(read), fp).......
```

Comment: **never** use sizeof(read). use strlen()!

Comment: Rach cannot use strlen, because the string will not have been read in yet. Of course, it would also need to be null terminated.

Comment: @BlackBear: `sizeof()` is perfectly good here.  He wants the storage size of the buffer, not the length of the string inside.  In fact, it's uninitialized so `strlen()` would be dangerous.

Comment: @Ben: yep. Misread for pointer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know your max. linesize you can read char by char and use realloc, then it's easy:

```
char *read = calloc(1,1),c;

while( c=fgetc(fp), !feof(fp) )
  if( c=='\n' )
  {
    puts(read);
    *read=0;
  }
  else
  {
    read = realloc(read,strlen(read)+2);
    read[strlen(read)+1]=0;
    strncat(read,&c,1);
  }
fclose(fp);
if( *read )
  puts(read);
free(read);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to just keep reallocating and appending to a buffer until you reach the end of the line. The code isn't pretty, but there isn't a simple alternative using the standard C library:

```
char read[30];
char *line;
int len, total;

line = NULL;
total = 0;

do {
  if (fgets(read, sizeof(read), fp) == NULL)
    break;

  len = strlen(read);

  if (total == 0) {
    total = len;
    line = (char *)malloc(len);
    strcpy(line, read);
  } else {
    total += len;
    line = (char *)realloc(line, total);
    strcat(line, read);
  }
} while (read[len - 1] != '\n');
```

Comment: Rather than writing this all over the place, if you need to support arbitrary-length line reads, you should probably write a function for it. You could use `getline` which is available on POSIX 2008 systems, and write your own replacement for it on systems that lack it; it has a simple API and it's widely available. The only potential problem is that it has bad behavior on allocation failure (you cannot reliably determine how much was read and recover the partially-read data).

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a safe reasonable maximum length for the line and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the C standard library you will just have to accept some maximum line size there and go with it.  If you detect that `read` does not end in a newline you could read more and append the additional data until you find the end of a line.  However, for most applications where `fgets()` is acceptable for parsing, a fixed line length is also acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

There's an off by one in your fgets(). If your buffer has a size of 30, you need to use sizeof(read)+1. Like Felice said, you'll need to set a safe maximum.

Comment: Huh? Adding 1 is not correct. It will result in buffer overflow.

Comment: From the man page of fgets(): "If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.  A '\0'  is  stored  after the last character in the buffer."
So after 30 bytes are read, the added '\0' will be out of the buffer.

Comment: Read carefully -- `fgets` reads at most `len - 1` characters into the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You have (at least) two choices. By far the most common is to allocate a buffer assumed to be "big enough" (e.g., a couple of kilobytes) and just go with it (and quite possibly mis-behave if provided with data that doesn't fit that limitation).

The primary alternative is to allocate the memory for the buffer dynamically, and when/if that data you read doesn't fit, use `realloc` to increase the buffer size and read some more.

Comment: Depending on your application, you might want to detect truncated lines (the `\n` at the end will be missing if `fgets` didn't read the whole lone), and then enter a `getc` loop throwing away characters until you reach `\n` or `EOF`. Otherwise the remainder of the line could be processed as a new line on the next loop iteration, possibly with bad results.